# jQuery UI resizable problem when adding elements on the fly

Tags: jquery

I'm using the UI resizable to expand  the viewform (id) and when I start to resize the viewform (id) and then I add element on the fly in it the box will not expand anymore.

Its easier if you look at this screencast I did to explain http://screencast.com/t/TmCzYg8HFSvd

```
$( "#viewform" ).resizable({
        minWidth: 560
    }); 

<div class="box" id="viewform"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the resizer adds a height once you start resizing the element, and so it stops following the size of the contents.

If you want to only resize in width, and keep the height always relative to its contents, you will need to use the `.stop` event and reset the height to `auto`

```
$("#viewform" ).resizable({
    minWidth: 560,
    stop: function(event, ui) {       
        $(ui.element).height('auto');
    }
 });
```

demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/Me8AG/